# Hide the touch keyboard on tab/next (editing a textbox)

Tags: android, xaml, uno-platform

Using a simple XAML textbox (C#/uno-platform) how can i solve the problem of hiding the touch keyboard (on Android) and focus in the next textbox or button, using the tab/next (or return) key? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNQR7.png)

textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textboxNumber" Width="120" PlaceholderText="Num" Margin="5,2" 
         InputScope="Number" TextAlignment="Center"
         FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" MaxLength="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source package that you can install that does what you want.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nventive.View.Uno

### How to use

Make sure you have the following in your XAML namespaces

```
xmlns:nve="using:Nventive.View.Extensions"
```

1. Use `TextBoxBehavior.NextControl` to move focus to another focusable field by pressing the enter key.
2. Use `TextBoxBehavior.DismissKeyboardOnEnter` to dismiss the keyboard by pressing the enter key.

### Example

```
<TextBox x:Name="EmailTextBox"
        PlaceholderText="Email"
        Text="{Binding Form.Email, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        nve:TextBoxBehavior.NextControl="{Binding ElementName=PasswordBox}" />

<PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox"
            PlaceholderText="Password"
            Password="{Binding Form.Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            nve:PasswordBoxBehavior.DismissKeyboardOnEnter="True"
            nve:PasswordBoxBehavior.EnterCommand="{Binding SignIn}" />
```